# How to place n objects(arcs) around the circle without them overlapping taking into account their preferred angle?

Tags: c++, c++11, geometry

I need to place `n` objects(arcs) on a circle circumference. Each object has its size in rads(degrees) and a **preferred position** in rads. It's known that sum of object sizes is < PI*2 so they all can fit in.
There would be 20-25 objects top, usually a smaller number and sizes are less than 20 degrees(each object can have a different size).

If objects overlap then they need to be moved from each other a little until they no longer overlap.

Any ideas or directions in which to dig are welcome.

For example if I have five 2 degrees objects with preferred position at 0 degrees, I want 3rd object to be on 0 degrees and first two CCW from 0 and 4,5 CW from 0. I'm not sure if it's possible though. (1,2,3,4,5 - order of their addition into the circle, they can be interleaved with objects at other angular positions). This way of resolving collisions is preferred but not very critical and I can cope with 1 on zero degrees and 4 others CW from it or CCW or any other. **The main goal is to place all objects on a circle without overlap and not far away from preferred angle.**

To check if arcs overlap I use this small algorithm from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160423072413/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/67287.html):

```
static constexpr double pi2 = 2*M_PI;
inline float posMod(float a, float n){
    return a - n * floor(a/n);
}

bool overlaps ( float arc1Start, float arc1Size, float arc2Start, float arc2Size ) {
    float c = posMod(arc2Start - arc1Start, pi2);
    float d = posMod(arc2Start + arc2Size - arc1Start, pi2);
    return arc1Size > c || c > d;//overlap. I've removed >=
    //if(b < c && c < d){
    //  //do not overlap
    //}
}
```

Maybe context will help to clarify a few things. I have round circle creatures that can evolve sensors(and other things) on their surface with arbitrary position(in rads) and size(in rads). I don't want them to overlap. And don't want sensor to be far away from a wanted position.

Comment: If determination is not possible I would use iterration.The idea is to use simple physics engine handling the circles as magnets that can only move on theire own ray starting from the middle. These magnetic circles would distract each other and attract to the common center. In a while they wouldn't move farther and this would be the solution positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution to my problem. It's not ideal, but the best I was able to come up with. It's not optimal in error and can use some optimization. It assumes that sum of arc sizes is less than 360 degrees. And doesn't guarantee to work at all if it gets into the looped state(there is an iteration max - 360. Can be less, depending on the number of arcs possible. Just a precaution, I wasn't able to inf loop it).
Its worst case scenario is O(n^3) I think where n is the number of arcs to be added(doesn't take into account possible infinite loop).

Full code: https://gist.github.com/avasilkov/8132266273a7edefe6df

Video how it looks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7QkNU0jZoI

Gist of the algorithm:

First I have empty circle. Then, when I want to add a new arc, I check if it overlaps any of already added arcs.
If no overlaps catched - adding this arc and we are done.

```
Arc arc(angleDestRef, preferredAngle, arcSize);
std::vector<int> ovs = getOverlapped(arc, -1);//overlapped arcs

if(ovs.size() == 0){
    arcs.push_back(arc);
    return;
}
```

If there is an overlap(1 or more), I iterate over overlapped arcs(including the arc we want to add, but it's not in the added arcs yet) and sum up their size and find an average of their position.
I again check for overlaps but this time for this new arc with center in average and size that I've just found.
(while summing up I make approximate center(refAngle) of the new larger arc to be zero(start of the circle) and for averaging to work I normalize all positions to be between -180 +180 degrees)

```
float dummy;
Arc buffArc(dummy, 0.0f, 0.0f);
int iterCount = 0;
float refAngle = arc.cAngle;
while(iterCount++ < 360){
    float cAngle = normalizeAngle(arc.pAngle - refAngle);
    float size = arc.size;
    for(int i : ovs){
        cAngle += normalizeAngle(arcs[i].pAngle - refAngle);
        size += arcs[i].size;
    }
    cAngle /= ovs.size() + 1.0f;
    cAngle += refAngle;
    cAngle = posMod(cAngle, pi2);
    refAngle = cAngle;
    buffArc.set(cAngle, size);
    std::vector<int> ovsBefore = std::move(ovs);
    ovs = getOverlapped(buffArc, -1);
```

If I get that the same arcs overlapped, then I exit while loop and add my arc to the main array.

```
if(ovs.size() != ovsBefore.size()){
    continue;
}

bool stopIter = true;
loopy(i, ovs.size()){
    if(ovs[i] != ovsBefore[i]){
        stopIter = false;
        break;
    }
}
if(stopIter){
    iterCount = 10000;
    break;
}
}
arcs.push_back(arc);
ovs.push_back(arcs.size() - 1);
```

Next I sort overlapped arcs in CCW order and change their current angle to a new one.

```
auto& _arcs = arcs;
std::sort(ovs.begin(), ovs.end(),
     [buffArc, _arcs](const int a, const int b){
         return angleDiff(buffArc.cAngle, _arcs[a].pAngle) < angleDiff(buffArc.cAngle, _arcs[b].pAngle);
     }
);
float startAngle = buffArc.cAngle - buffArc.hs;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < ovs.size(); i++){
    Arc& _arc = arcs[ovs[i]];
    startAngle += _arc.size;
    _arc.cAngle = startAngle - _arc.hs;
}
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBMvQFBLv8k
Another version of the algorithm in which first I find maximum size among all arcs and make all arcs occupy this max size and not original(you can see wide transparent sectors - space occupied, and opaque arc - actual arc size). But this was even worse solution if you count total distance among all arcs actual angles and their requested ones.